# Is there any way to use tika library on pythonanywhere?

Tags: java, django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

**I'm working on a parsing problem and have used tika library in local system to read pdf documents. As now I'm deploying my parser on the web, I'm not allowed to use tika library on pythonanywhere server. I have read that pythonanywhere don't support tika but I'm import and installing anyway on server without error. I'm stuck with it from couple days now.**

```
2020-04-08 11:49:26,003: Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.24/tika-server-1.24.jar to /tmp/tika-server.jar.
2020-04-08 11:49:26,006: Exception on /parser [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 798, in getRemoteJar
    urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/mysite/server.py", line 1546, in hello
    response = read_pdf(name.filename)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/mysite/server.py", line 115, in read_pdf
    file_data = parser.from_file(file)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/parser.py", line 40, in from_file
    output = parse1(service, filename, serverEndpoint, headers=headers, config_path=config_path, requestOptions=requestOptions)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 338, in parse1
    rawResponse=rawResponse, requestOptions=requestOptions)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 531, in callServer
    serverEndpoint = checkTikaServer(scheme, serverHost, port, tikaServerJar, classpath, config_path)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 592, in checkTikaServer
    getRemoteJar(tikaServerJar, jarPath)
  File "/home/mubasharnazar/.virtualenvs/flaskk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tika/tika.py", line 808, in getRemoteJar
    urlretrieve(urlOrPath, destPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

**Any solution would be highly appreciated?**

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace, including the error message at the bottom?

Comment: @GilesThomas I have updated the question now, plz have a look.

Comment: Looks like you are on a free account and try to connect to the site from outside the whitelist. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Comment: ok so domain name is mubasharnazar.pythonanywhere.com. Do you mean that i need to request to include it in the whitelist?